# SELECT WHERE IN with logical AND statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to select only objects which are in all three groups (1,2,3).
With the "WHERE gid IN (1,2,3)" Select i get an OR selection. What i need is an AND selection.

```
OBJECT_TABLE AS o  
id | field1 | field2 | ...  

 VALUES  
 1, a, b  
 2, c, d  
 3, e, f  
 ...


GROUP_XREF_TABLE AS gx   
 oid | gid  

VALUES  
1, 1  
1, 2  
1, 3  
2, 2  
3, 1  
3, 2  
...


SELECT DISTINCT o.id, gx.gid FROM `OBJECT_TABLE`  AS o
LEFT JOIN `GROUP_XREF_TABLE` AS gx ON o.id = gx.oid
WHERE gx.gid IN (1,2,3)
```

This outputs all rows. I need an WHERE clause which outputs only rows with the object id 1, because only that object is in all three groups.

Its part of a larger select, so its important that this should be done only within the where statement (subselects should be fine if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subselect below will find those oid:s that have 3 rows in gx:

```
SELECT o.id, gx.gid FROM `OBJECT_TABLE`  AS o
LEFT JOIN `GROUP_XREF_TABLE` AS gx ON o.id = gx.oid
WHERE gx.oid IN (
    SELECT oid FROM GROUP_XREF_TABLE as gx2 
     GROUP BY oid
    HAVING count(*) = 3)
```

Comment: thanks! this should work, but i get no results at all. i think SELECT oid should be gid?

Comment: i actually had to extend it, cause your query got me objects which are in any kind of groups as long as they are three of them. i need to specify groups. so i did this: 
WHERE gx.oid IN (SELECT oid FROM GROUP_XREF_TABLE as gx2 WHERE gid IN (1,2,3) GROUP BY oid HAVING count(*) = 3)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT  o.id, gx.gid FROM `OBJECT_TABLE`  AS o
   LEFT JOIN `GROUP_XREF_TABLE` AS gx ON o.id = gx.oid
   WHERE gx.gid IN (1,2,3)
   group by gx.gid
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/247e6/21)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but this answer is not correct - it produces the correct output given the data, but only by coincidence. If you add record (3,3) to GROUP_XREF_TABLE, you should see rows for both 1 and 3, but you don't - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90fdf/1 .